# Find an element by tag using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Requirement Description:**

I have a page in which there is a description section. The description section is basically a big html section consists of `images` and `texts`.

So if a user clicks on an **image**, then the user should be **redirected to another page** which has only the **description data** in it. After redirection, **the page should scroll itself to that clicked image**.

**Standard Solution**

I know the issue is easy if we have the `id` for each image, such that we can send the `id` in the `url` with the `hash` and then using `$anchorscroll`, the page will automatically scrolls to that clicked image.

**Actual Problem**

But the issue is that i dont have an `id` with the `img` tag.

The html of `description section` is like this:

```
....
<div class="someclass"><img src="cdn url of the image"></div>
....
```

Please note that there is no such particular format of the html structure. 
 It can be in any form.
 But the img tag contains only src.

The other page also has the same description data and HTML structure as the previous. I just need to scroll the page to the clicked image.
What can be the solution?

Comment: any reason for negative rankings. please ?

Comment: CSS selectors allow for any CSS selector, not just ids. In your case, `document.querySelector("div.someClass img")` will do the job, although I would be very surprised if angular won't let you add references to elements directly, so you don't even need to do *any* query selecting, but just access the element based on its angular binding.

Comment: I cannot use a class to find image as the data is entered through a CMS and it can be in any form. Although i'm trying to add the references through angular. But i was confused whether that would be a heavy option to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practises to do such things with AngularJS.
Anyway, I made you a function that will search for images that only contain `src` attributes.

But be carefull, if you remove or manipulate the elements, remember to call the `$scope.$apply()` Method! Otherwise AngularJS will not know that any element has been changed.

```
/**
 * Gets all images with only a src attribute
 * @param element Any element from where to start the function. If not defined document will be used
 * @returns {Array} An array of Matching element
 */
function getMyImages(element) {
    element = element || document;
    var images = element.querySelectorAll('img[src]');//Get all images with src attributes
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = images.length; i < j; i++) {

        var attributes = images[i].attributes;

        if (attributes.length > 1) {//Skip images with more than one attribute
            continue;
        }
        if (attributes[0].name === 'src') {//if the attribute is a src attribute, add it to the matches
            matches.push(images[i]);
        }
    }

    return matches;//Matches will now just contain images with only src attribute
}
```

Comment: im trying your solution but as the data comes in through an API call. So as of now, i'm getting `element` as undefined since the data comes after sometime. I'm trying inside the directive using the `post link`. but no luck

Comment: you have to call the method after the response is inside of the DOM.
If you are using the `$http` Service call the method inside if the `success` block

Comment: If the method is inside of a directive that hasn't any controll of the ajax call, then you have to make your own response listener. check out `$broadcast` and `$on`

Comment: i'm doing like this 

`var div = document.createElement('div');`
 `div.innerHTML = element[0].innerHTML;`
  `console.log(div.children.querySelectorAll('img[src]'));`

But querySelectorAll is undefined function. Any idea ?

Comment: `console.log(div.children.querySelectorAll('img[src]'));` should be `console.log(div.querySelectorAll('img[src]'));`